# java, the principle logic behind l = inputStream.readLine()) != null

Tags: java, io

I'm new to java and is having trouble understand some of the basic principles shown by the example below. Could someone please explain the meaning of l = inputStream.readLine()) != null in the context of the code below? your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CopyLines {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader inputStream = null;
    PrintWriter outputStream = null;

    try {
        inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("xanadu.txt"));
        outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("characteroutput.txt"));

        String l;
        while ((l = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
            outputStream.println(l);
        }
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
        if (outputStream != null) {
            outputStream.close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This code

```
while ((l = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
    outputStream.println(l);
}
```

is the *equivalent* of

```
l = inputStream.readLine();
while (l != null)
{

    l = inputStream.readLine();
}
```

So, when a reader cannot read a new line, it returns `null`, which breaks the loop.

Answer (score 2):

`readLine()` returns `null` when end of stream is reached . so , here
   `while ((l = inputStream.readLine()) != null)`  , we check if `l` is not equal to `null` before we can keep reading from the file.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code snippet taken from your question:

```
while ((l = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
    outputStream.println(l);
}
```

The assignment statement `l = inputStream.readLine()` returns `null` if a `null` assignment is made (i.e. if `inputStream.readLine()` returns `null`).  So this is just a shorthand for the following:

```
l = inputStream.readLine();
while (l != null) {
    outputStream.println(l);
    l = inputStream.readLine()
}
```

It may not be obvious, but the assignment operator (`=`) is a function, and using it is calling a function much in the way we usually think in Java.  So the following if statement will not execute:

```
String foobar;
if ((foobar = "string") == null) {
}
```

But this one will:

```
String foobar;
if ((foobar = null) == null) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the while ((l = inputStream.readLine()) != null){...} statements means that :

1.the program use an while-loop to read the file.

2.each iteration it read one line.

3.the while-loop will end when the line it read is end,which means u reach the end of file(EOF).

I think the more u concern is why we write the code this way.

In my opinion, its just a convention of programmers.

It makes the code look shorter and ideographic.

Because u can run a statement which return a boolean expression in a while statement.So sometimes we put so iterative behavior in it to make the code shorter.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning is you are assigning the value received by input.readLine() method to the variable l of type String and checking if the value is not null.